# help understanding functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis

How to get a good intuition on infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces and concepts such as weak convergence and the other abstract results ?
Thanks

Comment: What do you know about dimension of a vector space?

Comment: It's all about $\mathbb L^2$, my friend.

Comment: By working on concrete problems involving the aforementioned objects.